# ReflectionTypeLoadException on DLL load

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, mef

I'm trying to realize a plugin framework with MEF. I have 3 projects:

- A host project (WPF)
- An interface definition project (portable class library)
- An plugin project (portable class library)

Now in the host, I try to load the plugin assemly dll (showing only the class that should load the dll):

```
public class SafeDirectoryCatalog : ComposablePartCatalog
{
    private readonly AggregateCatalog _catalog;

    public SafeDirectoryCatalog(string directory)
    {
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, "*.dll", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

        _catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            try
            {
                var asmCat = new AssemblyCatalog(file);

                if (asmCat.Parts.ToList().Count > 0)
                {
                    _catalog.Catalogs.Add(asmCat);
                }

            }
            catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException)
            {
            }
            catch (BadImageFormatException)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    public override IQueryable<ComposablePartDefinition> Parts
    {
        get { return _catalog.Parts; }
    }
}
```

on

```
var asmCat = new AssemblyCatalog(file);
```

I can see, that there is a "ReflectionTypeLoadException" and the parts list es emtpy:

[Exception Screenshot (VS is German)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR6oV.png)

This is my interface definition (outputs a dll that is referenced in the host and the plugin project):

```
namespace HCInterfaces
{
    public interface HomeControlInterface
    {
        string GetModuleName();
    }
}
```

And finally this is my Plugin class that outputs the plugin.dll:

```
using HCInterfaces;
using System.Composition;

namespace Plugin2
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {

        }


        [Export(typeof(HomeControlInterface))]
        class BMW : HomeControlInterface
        {
            public string GetModuleName()
            {
                return "hännschenklein";
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue will probably be library reference incompatibilities.
Maybe this link will help:

[MEF 2 Composition with .NET 4.5, Windows Store PCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22033393/mef-2-composition-with-net-4-5-windows-store-pcl)